# Passing remediation actions as parameter in cloud formation for aws config template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-systems-manager

I am currently working on automating aws config rule creation using cloudformation template. I need to add remediation actions in script for automating the non complient resources.
I have no idea for adding the remediation actions as parameters for cloud formation templates. 
Can someone help me solve this issue? Below is my code. But I am not able to create stack

```
{
"Resources": {
"AWSConfigRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::Config::ConfigRule",
  "Properties": {
    "ConfigRuleName": {
      "Ref": "ConfigRuleName"
    },
    "Description": "Checks whether Amazon Virtual Private Cloud flow logs 
are found and enabled for Amazon VPC.",
    "InputParameters": {
      "trafficType": {
        "Fn::If": [
          "trafficType",
          {
            "Ref": "trafficType"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Scope": {},
    "Source": {
      "Owner": "AWS",
      "SourceIdentifier": "VPC_FLOW_LOGS_ENABLED"
    },
    "MaximumExecutionFrequency": {
      "Ref": "MaximumExecutionFrequency"
    },
    "RemediationConfigurations": {
        "Ref": "RemediationConfigurations"
    },        
  }
}
  },
 "Parameters": {
"ConfigRuleName": {
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "vpc-flow-logs-enabled",
  "Description": "The name that you assign to the AWS Config rule.",
  "MinLength": "1",
  "ConstraintDescription": "This parameter is required."
},
"MaximumExecutionFrequency": {
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "TwentyFour_Hours",
  "Description": "The frequency that you want AWS Config to run evaluations for the rule.",
  "MinLength": "1",
  "ConstraintDescription": "This parameter is required.",
  "AllowedValues": [
    "One_Hour",
    "Three_Hours",
    "Six_Hours",
    "Twelve_Hours",
    "TwentyFour_Hours"
  ]
},
"trafficType": {
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "",
  "Description": "TrafficType of flow logs"
},
"RemediationConfigurations": [ 
  { 
     "TargetId": "AWS-PublishSNSNotification",
     "TargetType": "SSM_DOCUMENT"
  }
]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property available like "RemediationConfigurations" for configrules that you can use it cloudfront directly. So you better invoke lambda function and pass it via script using the function putremediationconfigurations.